# Upload resized image to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, boto

I'm trying to upload resized image to S3:

```
fp = urllib.urlopen('http:/example.com/test.png')
img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())

im = Image.open(img)
im2 = im.resize((500, 100), Image.NEAREST)  
AK = 'xx' # Access Key ID 
SK = 'xx' # Secret Access Key

conn = S3Connection(AK,SK) 
b = conn.get_bucket('example')
k = Key(b)
k.key = 'example.png'
k.set_contents_from_filename(im2)
```

but I get an error:

```
 in set_contents_from_filename
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to convert your output image into a set of bytes before you can upload to s3.  You can either write the image to a file then upload the file, or you can use a cStringIO object to avoid writing to disk as I've done here:

```
import boto
import cStringIO
import urllib
import Image

#Retrieve our source image from a URL
fp = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com/test.png')

#Load the URL data into an image
img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())
im = Image.open(img)

#Resize the image
im2 = im.resize((500, 100), Image.NEAREST)  

#NOTE, we're saving the image into a cStringIO object to avoid writing to disk
out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
#You MUST specify the file type because there is no file name to discern it from
im2.save(out_im2, 'PNG')

#Now we connect to our s3 bucket and upload from memory
#credentials stored in environment AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
conn = boto.connect_s3()

#Connect to bucket and create key
b = conn.get_bucket('example')
k = b.new_key('example.png')

#Note we're setting contents from the in-memory string provided by cStringIO
k.set_contents_from_string(out_im2.getvalue())
```

Comment: Where do you add a mimetype in this code?  I'm getting files to upload to S3 but they are appearing as unreadable files.

Comment: @captDaylight - To set the mime type add a  headers={"Content-Type": "image/png"}  as a parameter to the set_contents_from_string call. Boto will try to guess the mime type by default but this will allow you to  set it manually.

Comment: Great answer. One change I recommend is to use the awesome [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) rather than the outdated `urllib` module.

Comment: @tatlar I agree, requests is WAY better than urllib. I only used it here because it was used by the original poster.

Comment: Thanks @secretmike! This is the only post online which explains this clearly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `Key.set_contents_from_filename` expects a single string argument, but you are passing in `im2`, which is some other object type as returned by `Image.resize`.  I think you will need to write your resized image out to the filesystem as a name file and then pass that file name to `k.set_contents_from_filename`.  Otherwise find another method in the `Key` class that can get the image contents from an in-memory construct (StringIO or some object instance).

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("loading object", input_bucket, input_key)
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=input_key)
print("s3 get object response", response)

body = response['Body']

image = Image.open(body)

print ("generating thumbnail", output_width, output_height)

thumbnail = resizeimage.resize_thumbnail(
    image, [output_width, output_height])
body.close()

print ("saving thumbnail", output_format)

with io.BytesIO() as output:
    thumbnail.save(output, output_format)

    print ("uploading thumbnail", output_bucket, output_key)
    output.seek(0)
    s3client.put_object(Bucket=output_bucket, Key=output_key,
                        Body=output, ContentType=output_content_type)
```

Comment: i got this working in a lambda service, stream in and out.