# Saving to S3, but file is Blank

Tags: python, amazon-s3, png, binary-data

I was using this answer to upload a PNG to S3:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693577/815878

The file is being uploaded to S3 however whenever I double click on the image to display it the url is "about:blank" and the screen is blank.

When I download the image, it is showing up on my computer as the image I saved.  My last recourse was to manually test out the url.  I made the photo public then tried:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.png
```

which gives me this:

[image]

Is there another step from the answer above that is making the file upload improperly?  I'm going to paste my code (which is very similar to the link above) just in case...

```
image = Image.open(self.image)
conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
image.save(out_im2, 'PNG')
b = conn.get_bucket('new_test_bucket')
k = b.new_key(self.title+'.png')
k.set_contents_from_filename(out_im2.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm more of a PHP than a Python guy, but from what I know Amazon S3 Requires defining the type of the file.

You need to send a mime type (e.g. image/png) for the server to recognize the file, since the S3 isn't an actual web server, it doesn't care much for the extension of your file. You could just as much call it "dipididoo.moo" and as long as the type is image/png , it would work.

Comment: Also, check your permissions.  I had a heck of a time with it.

Comment: As i said im not a PHP guy so i have no idea. If you have any option to add a custom HTTP Header add Content-Type: image/png

Answer (score 1):

Set mimetype as below:

```
k.set_contents_from_filename(out_im2.getvalue(), {'Content-Type' : 'image/png'})
```