# Issues in saving resized file on S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I am resizing an image using PIL on S3 but its giving error of

```
*** AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

Here is my code :

```
image = Image.open(self.file)
resized_image = image.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

 bucket = s3_connection()
 k = Key(bucket)
 filepath = '{0}/{1}'.format(filepath,filename) # filepath & filename values will be received 
 k.key = '{0}/{1}'.format('media', filepath) 
 k.set_contents_from_file(resized_image.tobytes()) <- This line is raising the above error.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `self.file` instead of `file` in the line `k.set_contents_from_file(file)`?

Comment: @MichielOvertoom I just copied the main lines from my code , self.file is original imahe , while I ahve to save resized image . I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

need to use `set_contents_from_string()` instead of `set_contents_from_file()`

For more details refer to this question [Upload resized image to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685500/upload-resized-image-to-s3)